# Am able to find the element using xpath. but however its not running while executing the script

Tags: selenium

Am able to find the element using xpath. but however its not running while executing the script. The element which am trying is inside the frame.Am able to switch the frame , but not able to find the element while running the script. I tried in my friend's machine. Its working. But not for me.

Comment: Okay, and where is your code?

Comment: Provide code snippet and have you verified element is dynamic? Also, check after adding wait to resolve your issue.